# How to perform both Render and Redirect for a given Action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn, prawnto

i m working on an app in rails that requires the following :

1. Clicking on a button should first download a pdf file (render part) and
2. Then redirect to a show page (redirect_to part)

I 've searched the web and found that it is not possible to render and redirect at the same time for a given action , is there any ways around this issue ?

Comment: you could use two functions, 1 for render and another for redirect

Comment: this is a bad way but you can use `if(something) render else redirect_to` this stuff better use `respond_to do |format| format.html{redirect_to ...} format.json {render @users} end`

Comment: This isn't just a rails limitation - for a single http request there can only be one response

Answer (score 1):

You could send the user to a result page and add a meta tag to redirect the user to a download after x seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://path_to/your/download.zip"/>
```

This is the approach you see at a lot of sites e.g. sourceforge.net (Your download will start after x seconds...)

Answer (score 0):

`send_data` using render, so you can't do anything after it in your controller.

To do this you have to use javascript:

1. Create a iframe on button click. (That will hold your download process).
2. Redirect the page on the iframe's close event.

You can also use a background job for download action but I haven't used it yet.

Comment: What do you mean by the iframe's close event?